# App rejected, impersonation policy Google Play. Could it be package name?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, google-apps, phonegap

first time building and publishing an app.
I used PhoneGap to create an app.

I got this message when i tried to publish the app on Google play.
**App violates the impersonation policy**

Not sure if the problem is the package name.
My package name: com.phonegap.organisationnameappname
Should it be like this instead:  com.organisationname.appname

I am using phonegap in the package name, could this be the cause of the violation.

I am using content form the organisations/company's website to create this app.
The app is for them. I am using my personal developers account to publish the app. Could this be the issue. Using my account to publish the app for them?

**Concerning the package name.**
Example: com.organisationname.appname 
What happens if you don't have an organisation name or organisation website? Can you use any name as an organisation name?

Can you have a package name like this: com.appname with no organisation name?

Is it possible to have more than one app on the app store with the same package name?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it might be the case with content. Google play just thinks that you are trying to mislead users. It also can be app name.

Comment: if you have legal rights to use company's content try contacting google - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/2993242?visit_id=1-636145321498752102-1429228295&rd=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you cannot use any brand or company name in package or in name without permission.
Please read Impersonation and Intellectual Property guidelines:
https://play.google.com/about/ip-impersonation/

Comment: Hi, in the package name. Do I have to add the company name? 
Example: com.appname.appname can it be just like this com.appname. What happens if there is an app with the same package name

Comment: you cannot use any registered or patent company name in package name or in app name. you can use "com" at the start of any package name or any other word. after com place dot e.g com. than place your play store developer name com.developername than you can use game or app name after com.developername.   and it will become com.developername.mygame

Comment: Thanks Malik, this was my problem. After changing the package name it worked.

Comment: @charmGeld happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your app includes any image, logo, name etc. belonging to some brand, that would be counted as policy violation. Detailed explanation is presented in Developer Policy Center linked below. Note that, there will be violation even if the brand is not on Google Play which means if you are using something e.g company logo that you are developing app for, that could be the counted as policy violation by Google Play.

https://play.google.com/about/ip-impersonation/